# Loading images in a try-catch block, have catch block respond to a specific failed image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am creating a simple GUI program that loads a few image files in a try-catch block. I was wondering how I would go about using my catch statement to load a default image to replace the specific image(s) that failed to be loaded? Here is the example I have in mind:

```
try{
    load image1
    load image2
    load image3
}catch (IOException e) {
    S.o.p("imageX failed to load")
    load defaultImage over image(s)X
}
```

So say image 2 failed to be found, the program would have successfully loaded images 1 and 3, and loaded the default image for image 2. Or in the event where multiple images failed to load, it could detect which specific images failed to load and replace them with a default image.

edit:
As @robertf suggested, I turned it into a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If image 2 fails to load, the exception would be thrown and only image 1 would be loaded.

How about creating a load method to do what you want?  In that method you would have your try/catch default image processing.

```
void main() {
    load(image1);
    load(image2);
    load(image3);
}
void load(image) {
    try {
       loadFile(image);
    }
    catch {
      loadFile(default);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thank you! making it a separate method is a lot more simple that i was trying to make it and worked like a charm.